# Why extension for UIView does not showing direct effect on other control except UIView placed on IB?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

For e.g.

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView{
    @IBInspectable var fillColor:UIColor?{
        set{
            backgroundColor=newValue
        }
        get{
            return backgroundColor//UIColor(cgColor: backgroundColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is unnecessary but just for checking I have created this and found this is working directly if applied in UIView else its not working.

Can anybody please suggest me am I missing something? I am using swift 3.0.2.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

When you are extending a UIView

```
class AJView:UIView{
    @IBInspectable var fillColor:UIColor? {
       didSet {
           layer.backgroundColor = fillColor.cgColor
       }
    }
}
```

When Using With extension

```
     extension BTextField{
    @IBInspectable var fillColor:UIColor? {
        get{
            return self.fillColor
        }
        set {
            layer.backgroundColor = self.fillColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works. 
I have edited the answer, you can check now

Comment: this is wrong answer... Since layer.backgroundColor is cgColor not UIColor and extension should not have stored properties. So can you please be more specific... Thanks anyway for your effort :)

Comment: please you stop repeating same mistakes... I have already mention your mistakes.